# TestNG. Need to run specific method before all tests and specifiic test after all tests

Tags: maven, testng

Used Selenium + TestNG + Maven.

I want to automate testing vulnerabilities using OWASP ZAP. For this I need to start ZAProxyScanner before all tests - execute method before all tests.

```
public void initZap(){
        zapScanner = new ZAProxyScanner(ZAP_PROXYHOST,ZAP_PROXYPORT,ZAP_APIKEY);
        zapScanner.clear(); //Start a new session
        zapSpider = (Spider)zapScanner;
}
```

and when all functional tests were executed - run test for searching vulnerabilities

```
@Test
public void scanning() throws ClientApiException{
    spiderWithZap();
    setAlertAndAttackStrength();
    zapScanner.setEnablePassiveScan(true);
    scanWithZap();
}
```

Method and test located in one class, e.g. `public class TestSecurity`

Here is sample of my testng.xml with packages containing functional tests

```
<suite name="Chrome" thread-count="1" parallel="tests" configfailurepolicy="continue">
<test name="chrome">
    <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>
    <packages>
        <package name="tests.suiteLogIn"></package>
        <package name="tests.suiteSettings"></package>
        <package name="tests.suiteSearch"></package>
    </packages>    
</test>
```

UPD. post modified code with AfterTest in it.
I use only Before/AfterMethod annotations

```
    @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun=true)
@Parameters({"browser", "environment"})
public void setUp(@Optional ("firefox") String browser, @Optional ("local") String environment, Method method) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Test name: " + method.getName());  
    WebDriver driver = getMyDriver(browser, environment);
    System.setProperty(ESCAPE_PROPERTY, "false");
}

@AfterMethod(alwaysRun=true)
@Parameters("browser")
public void tearDown(@Optional ("firefox") String browser){
    DriverMaster.stopDriver();
}

@BeforeSuite
@Parameters("browser")
public void startZap(@Optional ("firefox") String browser){
    if(browser.equals("firefox")){
        sec.initZap();
    }
}

@AfterSuite
@Parameters("browser")
public void scanZap(@Optional ("firefox") String browser) throws ClientApiException{
    if(browser.equals("firefox")){
        LoginPage lp = new LoginPage(getDriverInstance()).load();
        lp.login("name", "pass");
        sec.scanning();
    }
}
```

Comment: In TestNG `@BeforeTest` or `@AfterTest` could help or `@BeforeSuite` or `@AfterSuite`.

Comment: @khmarbaise, looks that I doing smthing wrong(( please see updated question

Comment: A method is either a test or aftersuite .  Have just the '@AfterSuite' annotation and remove the '@Test'

Comment: @niharika_neo, but if I need to have scan results in testrun report, so it should be a marked as test? also, I remove '@Test' annotation, but this case '@AfterTest' doesn't start (@BeforeTest is starting)

Comment: Please post your modified code with AfterTest in it.  Are you referring to the testng reports?

Comment: @niharika_neo, find my fault. thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You basically have two options:

1. Use @BeforeSuite and @AfterSuite and include that in the files to run or make all your classes extend it
2. Use [ITestListener](https://javadoc.jitpack.io/com/github/cbeust/testng/master/javadoc/org/testng/ITestListener.html) or [ISuiteListener](https://javadoc.jitpack.io/com/github/cbeust/testng/master/javadoc/org/testng/ISuiteListener.html) and put the setup and teardown code in their before and after methods.

With listeners, one advantage that I can see is if you want to do conditional teardown (scanning) based on some testresults you can control that too.