# What is the last method to call after ALL test cases have run in JUnit

Tags: java, junit

In JUnit, setUp() is called before running "each" test case and tearDown() on completion of the run. But I want to know whether there is method that get called after running "all" test cases in the suite.

I need such a method to insert some instrumentation.

Comment: this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82949/before-and-after-suite-execution-hook-in-junit-4-x might help

Comment: There is a substantial difference between JUnit 3 and 4. Which one are you talking about? It kind of sounds like 3, which is now heavily outdated.

Comment: @SiKing It is Junit4

Comment: If you are using JUnit4, then the name of the method is irrelevant. JUnit4 uses annotations, as described by the answers here.

Answer (score 2):

`@After` annotation is used to indicate the method to be run after every `@Test`

Also, for reference:

To run method before a test:
`@Before` - executes before each `@Test`,
`@BeforeClass` - executes before all `@Tests`

To run method after a test:
`@After` - executes after each `@Test`,
`@AfterClass` - executes after all `@Tests`

Comment: Are you suggesting the solution mentioned here ?? stackoverflow.com/questions/9903341/… If that is the case, should I add all my test cases in @SuiteClasses??

Comment: here is a simple example: http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/After.html

Comment: there is nothing about 'after ALL test cases' in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the @BeforeClass and @AfterClass annotations.  They identify static methods to run before/after all the tests

Comment: that's running after a class, not after *all* of them

Comment: Right; not running after *each* test, but running once, only after all of the tests have run

Comment: Are you suggesting the solution mentioned here ?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903341/cleanup-after-all-junit-tests
If that is the case, should I add all my test cases in @SuiteClasses??

Comment: No need,   the \@AfterClass will run *once* *after* all the tests.  Any clean-up you need to do can be done there.  Even if you use your IDE to run just one test, the \@BeforeClass and \@AfterClass will run *once*