# Where to declare driver.close()

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

after my test is finished browser is not closed. I understand that i need to declare driver.close() method. But which practise is best, where should i declare that?

i need that after every test is finished (failed or passed, nvm), browser should be closed.

my test for exmpl.

```
public void createOrganization() throws InterruptedException {
        new loginPage()
                .loginToSystemAsVPTSpecialist();
        new createOrganization()
                .clickButtonCreateJA()
                .selectMembership()
                .clickButtonFillUserData();
    }
```

Comment: If you are using framworks like JUnit or TestNG, you can write a method that closes the driver and annotate it so it is called once after all test have finished. In Unit, it's [`@AfterAll`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.2/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/AfterAll.html)

Comment: Thank you for answer, but where i should put this method?

Comment: You can put that method in classes that contain tests. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903341/cleanup-after-all-junit-tests) (where the old annotation `@AfterClass` was used (JUnit 4)). There are alternatives as well.